# Como obtener el id del usuario logeado en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting, ec2

Estoy haciendo un script en php y necesito obtener el id del usuario, tengo este codigo:

```
<?php
    include_once 'wp-load.php';
    echo get_current_user_id(); 
?>
```

Pero me devuelve 0.

Es de aclarar que el script lo estoy haciendo fuera del entorno de Wordpress, es decir, es un archivo php individual, por eso hago el:

```
include_once 'wp-load.php';
```

Tambien debo aclarar que en localhost el script funciona bien, pero cuando lo subo a mi hosting (instancia ec2) me devuelve 0. Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo haces con `get_current_user_id()`, simplemente así: `echo get_current_user_id();`. [Ver la documentación](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/). No necesitas declarar `global` ni nada, simplemente invocar la función.

Comment: Hola Cedano, te comento que igual me devuelve 0. Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Patricio dice: *Return: The current user's ID, **or 0 if no user is logged in**.*, o sea, devuelve `0` si no hay ningún usuario logueado. ¿Seguro que hay un usuario logueado?

Comment: Sisi, estoy logeado y devuelve simplemente 0... nada mas

Comment: Hagamos esta prueba a ver qué pasa: `$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); var_dump($current_user);`  Comenta lo que devuelve el `var_dump`.

Comment: Devolvio esto: `object(WP_User)#9402 (8) { ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#9403 (0) { } ["ID"]=> int(0) ["caps"]=> array(0) { } ["cap_key"]=> NULL ["roles"]=> array(0) { } ["allcaps"]=> array(0) { } ["filter"]=> NULL ["site_id":"WP_User":private]=> int(0) }`

Comment: Da la impresión de que no hay ningún usuario logueado. Esto no falla, dirá la realidad del asunto: `if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Bienvenido!';
} else {
    echo 'Nadie logueado, eres un visitante!';
}` Prueba ver qué dice.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82696/discussion-between-patricio-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 1):

En realidad, el archivo que querés cargar es `wp-load.php`

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wp-load.php");
```

Luego probablemente necesites obtener el current user antes de poder ver su ID:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Victoria!, he realizado los cambios que me indicas pero sigue devolviendo 0 :(

Comment: @Patricio, si la respuesta de wp_get_current_user() es 0, significa que no está logueado el usuario. Podés verlo en la [documentación](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user).

Comment: Hola Victoria, he agegado mas detalles a la descripcion

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener esa información con `wp_get_current_user()`. Tal como lo indica la [documentación de Wordpress el objeto `WP_User` tiene varias propiedades](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user#Return_Values) que puedes obtener como el nombre de usuario, el slug, el email, etc.

Puedes utilizar una función que compruebe que el usuario esté loggeado en Wordpress de la siguiente manera:

```
function usuario_registrado() {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  return $user->exists();
}
```

Y obtener el ID del usuario de esta manera:

```
function usuario_id() {
  $usuario = wp_get_current_user();
  return $usuario->ID;
}
```

Dentro de la lógica de tu template puedes utilizar la primer función para manejar el caso de que el usuario no tenga una sesión iniciada.

```
if ( usuario_registrado() ) {
  $id = usuario_id();
}
```

Comment: Hola akko, he agegado mas detalles a la descripcion

Answer (score 0):

A través de la función [**`get_current_user_id()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/)  podemos obtener el ID del usuario logueado directamente, sin necesidad de manipular enteramente el objeto `user` de Wordpress.

El problema por el que no funciona ([ha sido dicho en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46566889#46566889)) es porque el OP estaba ejecutando el código **fuera del entorno de Wordpress**.

De estar dentro del entorno de Wordpress, con esto bastaría:

```
echo get_current_user_id();
```

Pero, al no estar en el entorno de WP, debemos incluir el archivo `wp-load`, que nos permitirá usar las diferentes funciones de Wordpress.

Por ejemplo:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require ('wp-load.php');  //poner la ruta correcta donde se encuentra el archivo
echo get_current_user_id();
```

En la primera línea, lo que estamos indicando es que no cargue las funcionalidades de las plantillas (las cuales también carga `wp-load`). Si también necesitas esas funcionalidades puedes eliminar esa línea en el código.

Para más detalles puedes consultar las respuestas a la pregunta: [***What is the correct way to use WordPress functions outside WordPress files?***](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47049)  en el área Wordpress de StackExchange.

Comment: Hola Cedano, he agegado mas detalles a la descripcion

Comment: @Patricio verifica que la ruta de `wp-load.php` es la correcta. Lo he probado así en mi hosting fuera del entorno de WP y funciona. En el enlace en inglés hay otro método (incluyendo otro archivo) el cual puedes probar también.

Comment: He probado todo eso pero sigue devolviendo 0.... y es solo en el wordpress de mi hosting, estoy sospechando que hay algo en la configuracion que esta mal....

Comment: Deberías revisar el log de errores en la carpeta dónde se ejecuta el script, para ver cuál es el motivo por el que no funciona, @Patricio.

Comment: No me aparece ningun log de errores en la carpeta donde se ejecuta el script, ¿como puedo hacer para que me empiecen a aparecer?. Gracias!

Comment: @Patricio puedes poner esto al inicio del script: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Luego deberá aparecer un archivo llamado `error_log` o similar donde habrá información sobre los errores ocurridos. Es una herramienta muy útil para depurar nuestro código sabiendo cuál es el problema y dónde se encuentra.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre el problema... el dia de ayer quise borrar un archivo por ftp y no me lo permitia... me decia que no tenia permisos... entonces a traves de ssh cambie los permisos de la carpeta html a 777... y ese era el problema... ahora probe cambiarlos a 755 y listo!, volvio a funcionar get_current_user_id(). Muchas gracias por sus ayudas!