# ¿Como solucionar conflicto entre wp-config.php y sdk de mercadopago?

Tags: php, wordpress

Estoy utilizando en mi sitio el plugin para woocomerce de mercadopago, pero a su vez ahora quiero realizar un script propio y utilizar el sdk de Mercadopago. El problema es que cuando incluyo ambos script en mi codigo (wp-config.php porque quiero realizar consultas y el de mercadopago) me da el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class MercadoPagoException, because the
>   name is already in use

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este conflicto?. Gracias!

Comment: `wp-config.php` es un archivo propio de Wordpress, el cual existe en tu sitio tengas Mercadopago o no. Lo que no entiendo es ¿por qué quieres agregar otro archivo llamado así? ¿qué tiene que ver eso con crear tu propio plugin? Casi seguro que entendiste algo mal en todo el proceso, no debes duplicar ese archivo bajo ningún concepto.

Comment: Jamas querria duplicar wp-config.php, estoy incluyendo este archivo porque el script que estoy usando es ajeno a wordpress, no lo estoy desarrollando dentro de wordpress. Gracias

Comment: Pero eso no tiene que ver, realmente `wp-config.php` no es un archivo *para incluir en ninguna parte*, como su nombre lo indica, ese archivo es el archivo de configuración de Wordpress y no tiene que ser incluido ni requerido en ninguna parte. Si lo que quieres es trabajar en el entorno de Wordpress desde fuera de Wordpress tienes que hacerlo de otro modo. En ese caso tendrías que incluir `wp-load.php`. [Mira si esta respuesta te sirve](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/193821/29967). Tampoco queda claro que sea eso lo que quieres porque tu planteamiento del problema no es del todo claro.

Comment: Ah ok, entiendo, voy a probarlo. Muchas Gracias!